# Retrieving attributes from another table using HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I am using Spring-MVC for my project. I have the classes as follows:

Pseudo Code:

```
public class A{
   @OneToMany(FetchType.Eager)
   private Set<ClassB> classB;
   public Set<ProductBasic> getProductBasic(){return productBasic;}
   // I also have a setter for above
}
```

For class A and class B in database, I have a foreign of 'class A' as 'ID' in 'class B'.
Now using HQL I want to retrieve the data from class A and class B together and display it. I have class B primary key and access to both tables. How shall I proceed using Hibernate Query language.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715149/how-to-fetch-data-dynamically-from-two-tables-using-hql-annotations-im-posti it will helpful you

Comment: Thanks askkuber, that was helpful, Although I am facing with a OnetoMany relationship and my query looks like this : "FROM User as u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.messages WHERE u.id="+personId. Is that correct?

Comment: If you are facing issue in Mapping it could be due to how you generated your Hibernate Java files? Its from Hibernate tool or manually?

Comment: What do you mean by Hibernate Java files in this context? I have written all code manually anyways.

Comment: How you wrote Java files for individual tables

Comment: Yes. Like I said, all code is written by me. I just wanted to know if the query I posted before is correct.

Comment: I can not comment on query without test it i think @mahesh already answer

Comment: @Orici I copied your query into the original question but you should probably make it match your sample code

Answer (score 0):

As you have mapping of both table already so by using following simple query you get data of both table. Here you will get set of classB's data for each classA object.

```
//    Session session get your session object
String hql = "FROM A";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List results = query.list();
```

Comment: I think there is some confusion. Lets say Class A is for User and class B is for msgs. When I give the primary key of classB(msg_id), I want to look up in database where is the msg_id, in which row, then check the user_id(foreign key), and retrieve records from class User as well.

Comment: Have you bidirectional mapping?  if yes then your required query shoulbe like this...                                                          Select b FROM classB b WHERE b.userId = b.classAObj.userId AND b.msgID='';

Comment: No bidirectional mapping, I thought as I need to process the class messages later on, I would not join the columns. Is it absolutely necessary to have bidirectional mapping?